# Isomorphisms between Alternating groups and modulo groups

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I'm studying Group theory at the moment and am struggling to see how $$\mathbb{A}_3\cong Z/3Z$$
How can you form an isomorphism that sends say (ijk) $\in \mathbb{A}_3$ to either of {0,1,2} $\in Z/3Z$ ?

Comment: Did you try any of the possibilities? There are not that many.

Comment: There are two such isomorphisms, each determined by where (123) is mapped to. It can be mapped to either 1 or 2. The rest follows. To see the mod 3 nature of what is going on, well, each of (123) and (132), the non-trivial elements in the group, is a 3-cycle, having mod 3 behaviour; when turned three times you get the identity.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the basics so correct me if I'm wrong. So homomorphisms have to map identity to identity so for a homomorphism $f$, $f(e)=0$. Then If I say $f(123)=1$ this leads to $$f((123)\cdot (132))=f(123)+f(132)$$
$$f(e)=1+f(132)$$
So then $f(132)$ must equal 2?

Comment: Yes, you've got it right; if $(1 2 3)$ goes to $1$, then consequently $(1 3 2)$ goes to $2$. This is a consequence of an important fact about homomorphisms: they preserve inverse relationships. Wherever you choose to send $(1 2 3)$, then $(1 3 2)$ must be sent to the inverse of that.

Comment: Got it thank you!